# click function not working angular2

Tags: angular

I am creating button inside my component at runtime and (click) is not  listening to the event

app.component.ts

```
        createButton() {
            '<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px;overflow: hidden">' +
              '<strong>' + line.title + '</strong>' +
              ' <ul style=" margin: 8px 0 0;">' +
              ' <li><span style="background: url(../../../../../assets/app-icons/arrow-popup.png) no-repeat;  width: 100%;height: 100%;background-size: 32%;padding: 0px 11px 13px 30px;">' + line.milage + '</span></li>' +
              ' <li><span  style="background: url(../../../../../assets/app-icons/view-popup.png) no-repeat;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-size:  18%;padding: 0px 11px 13px 30px;">KMZ (web)</span></li>' +
              '</ul>' +
              '<button role="button" (click)="viewCircuit()" style=" color: #18377C;font-size: 14px;display: block;text-align: right;">View</button>' +
              '</div>'
        }

    viewCircuit() {
          console.log('data')

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button (click)="myFunc()"></button>

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"button.html" //this is the component which has the above button html
})

export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  myFunc(){
    console.log("function called");
  }
}
```